# Optimization sorting on calculated field

Tags: mysql, sql

There are tables `users` and `address`. The second table has column `geo` with type **geometry**. During the searching users, current coords are sent on the server, and distance is calculated via such a sql request:

```
SELECT 
   FLOOR(ST_Distance_Sphere(point(lng, lat), `geo`)) as distance 
FROM 
  address 
WHERE
  condition
```

It works well, but also I need to sort by this field and it requires a lot of time.
Can someone advise how to optimize it?

**MYSQL 5.7**

Comment: Noway to optimize. Filesort. Try to limit returned rows count. PS. Does `lng, lat` are the columns from `users` table?

Comment: no, the mobile app sends them to the server, rows count already limit to 20, but still to long

Comment: *no, the mobile app sends them to the server* i.e. this is constants... *rows count already limit to 20, but still to long* I mean limiting before sorting, not after it. For example, select only the rows where the difference by one coordinate is below some distance.

Comment: it's an interesting idea, I've tried to avoid all users with distance great than 10km, but the result in big cities contains several thousand users anyway

Comment: `geo`???  It is supposed to be a number (meters of the diameter of the sphere).

Answer (score 0):

Classic problem.  No quick solution.  All solutions involve adding a "bounding box" to the `WHERE`, plus some index that makes use of that bounding box.  Here's my 'dissertation' on the problem, plus detailed solutions:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql

I am assuming hour "condition" includes

```
WHERE distance < 100
```

or

```
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 10
```